# ModelState is validating Id in a insert

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've tryed to merge my create and edit actions into a save action, but for some reason, when I try to insert a new Cliente, the modelState trys to validate de ID colum. If I comment out the hidden field ID in the view, it works.
Would you give me a clue, please!?

View

```
@model WebApplicationCursoASPNET_V3.ViewModels.FormularioClienteViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Novo";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2> Cliente</h2>

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Gravar", "Cliente"))
{

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.cliente.Nome)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cliente.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.cliente.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.cliente.TipoAssinaturaId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.cliente.TipoAssinaturaId, new SelectList(Model.tiposAssinatura, "Id", "Nome"), "<< Selecione a assinatura >>", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.cliente.TipoAssinaturaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.cliente.Aniversario)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.cliente.Aniversario, "{0:d}", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.cliente.Aniversario)
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.cliente.EstaInscritoEmAssinaturas) Está inscrito em assinaturas
        </label>
    </div> 
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.cliente.Id)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.cliente.Id, "", new {@class="text-danger"})
    <br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Gravar</button>
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Gravar(FormularioClienteViewModel dadosFormulario)
        {
            if (dadosFormulario.cliente.Id == 0)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.Clientes.Add(dadosFormulario.cliente);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cliente");
                }

                var vwModel = new FormularioClienteViewModel
                {
                    cliente = dadosFormulario.cliente,
                    tiposAssinatura = _context.TipoAssinaturas.OrderBy(m => m.Nome).ToList()
                };
                return View("Form", vwModel);
            }

            var clienteDB = _context.Clientes.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == dadosFormulario.cliente.Id);
            if (clienteDB == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            clienteDB.Nome = dadosFormulario.cliente.Nome;
            clienteDB.TipoAssinaturaId = dadosFormulario.cliente.TipoAssinaturaId;
            clienteDB.Aniversario = dadosFormulario.cliente.Aniversario;
            clienteDB.EstaInscritoEmAssinaturas = dadosFormulario.cliente.EstaInscritoEmAssinaturas;
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cliente");
        }
```

Model

```
 public class Cliente
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nome do cliente")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255,ErrorMessage = "Tamanho máximo de 255 caracteres")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Está inscrito em assinaturas")]
        public bool EstaInscritoEmAssinaturas { get; set; }

        public TipoAssinatura TipoAssinatura { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tipo de assinatura")]
        public int TipoAssinaturaId { get; set; }

        public DateTime? Aniversario { get; set; }
    }
```

Error msg: O campo Id é obrigatório. / Field Id is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, it is recommended to use different calls for save and update with different DTO.

In your case, now you need to make Id nullable and validate it with custom logic in Update.

```
public int? Id { get; set; }
```